# joomla broken index.php

Tags: joomla1.5

Here's what I did:

1. I wanted to install a module(called *mod_php*) and I read that I could
   just extract it to the *modules* directory
2. I went to the Modules
   manager and created a new Module instance of type *mod_php*
3. I directed it to an existing menu item
4. I got a 404 index.php not  found error
5. I Went back and undid all the changes I made and deleted
   manually the folder from the modules directory

Still index.php not found. I *can* access other files in the root directory, though, for  example - index2.php

Using Joomla! 1.5. Have you got any idea what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one I would update to 2.5 and try installing the module in module manager in the backend of Joomla so installation is run correctly.

Comment: Sadly, I cannot do this. I have no access to the server, I'm not an administrator. I was granted administrator rights to the back-end, though, and to the ftp server. So, could you suggest anything that I could do with the means I have? Thank you, anyway!

Comment: You can still install on 1.5 :) just add correct 1.5 package in back-end

Comment: You no need file access you upload the zip with installation xml inside valid for 1.5

Comment: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-modules/1758

Comment: I've had the same problem today, numerous times, and I concluded that you should never ever upload or change component or module files via ftp. Joomla just doesn't like its files being modified outside of the backend and it refuses to load index.php.